# Proof that the arc goes to zero in Inverse Laplace transform of $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\sqrt{s}\right\}$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, contour-integration

I am solving the following inverse Laplace transform $$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\sqrt{s}\right\}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} \sqrt{s} e^{st}ds $$
I have chosen the following Bromwich contour

[image]

My problem lies in the ability to show that the the integral along the arc AB (also the integral along the arc EF), from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi$ goes to zero as $R\rightarrow\infty$.
So far what I have done is the following:
Let $s=Re^{i\theta}$, then $$
\int_{
AB} \sqrt{s} e^{st}ds=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}R^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}} e^{xR({\cos\theta+i\sin\theta})}e^{i\theta}iRd\theta$$
Taking modulus in the integral we arrive at
$$R^{\frac{3}{2}}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} e^{xR({\cos\theta})}d\theta $$
Making the substitution $\theta=\frac{1}{2}+\phi $
$$R^{\frac{3}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  e^{-xR{\sin\phi}}d\phi\leq R^{\frac{3}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  e^{-xR{\frac{2}{\pi}\phi}}d\phi  $$
integrating the last integral I got 
$$ \frac{R^{\frac{1}{2}}\pi}{2x}\left[1-e^{-xR}\right]$$
which diverges as $R\rightarrow\infty$.
Can someone please help me showing where I went wrong in this process.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The inverse Laplace Transform of $\sqrt s$ fails to exist.  Note that 

$$\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\sqrt{s}e^{st}\,ds=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt{\gamma+is}\,\,e^{(\gamma+is)t}\,i\,ds$$

which diverges for all $t\ge 0$.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you Mark for your reply. So it seems that my calculations were correct!(?) It´s weird because this integral is solved here on page 16, Example 4.1.14  (pag 138). https://www.univie.ac.at/physikwiki/images/9/98/NewCH4.pdf

Comment: Notice that the answer in that example is $O(x^{-3/2})$, which clearly has no Laplace Transform since $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-sx}}{x^{3/2}}$ clearly diverges.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\right)$? That is simple since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is an eigenfunction for $\mathcal{L}$ (like $e^{-x^2}$ is an eigenfunction for $\mathcal{F}$).

Comment: @Jack D´Aurizio that was an example given in this paper  (Example 4.1.14) . The author even provides an answer.
 univie.ac.at/physikwiki/images/9/98/NewCH4.pdf

Comment: What likely happened is that the author took the result $$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left ( s^{-1/2} \right ) = (\pi t)^{-1/2}$$ and differentiated with respect to $t$.  Not really valid b/c of the convergence issues on the contour but there you go.